# closing an SDL-window without quitting SDL

Tags: window, sdl

i'm using SDL1.2 to handle window-management in my openGL framework.

is it possible to destroy a window (surface) while the program is running without calling `SDL_Quit()`?

background: my framework is really just one gfx component (of potentially many such gfx components) in a multimedia environment. i cannot make any assumptions on what the other components are goind to do (e.g. whether they use SDL). i'm afraid that calling `SDL_Quit()` will have side-effects on the other components.

currently i'm doing something like:

```
SDL_Surface m_surface=0;

bool create_window() {
   int videoFlags = SDL_OPENGL;
   if(m_surface) {
       pritnf("window already made\n");
       return false;
   }
   if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 ) {
       pritnf("unable to initialize SDLn");
       return false;
   }
   m_surface = SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BPP, videoFlags);

   return(m_surface!=0);
}

bool destroy_window() {
   if(m_surface) {
      SDL_Quit();
   }
   m_surface=0;
}
```

both `create_window()` and `destroy_window()` are supposed to get called multiple times during the life-cycle of the application.
however, it feels weird to call `SDL_Init()` and `SDL_Quit()` multiple times.

btw, i'm using linux right now, but i'm targetting cross-platform (at least linux, osx, w32)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with SDL 1.2, the screen surface has a special status and only `SDL_Quit()` can delete it. You can try using `SDL_QuitSubSystem()` to shutdown only the video part then `SDL_InitSubSystem()` to reinstate it, but I'm not sure it will work (I can't test this right now).

On the other hand, it looks easy to do with SDL 2.0 with `SDL_CreateWindow()` and `SDL_DestroyWindow()`.

Either way, you would need to separate initialization (`SDL_Init()`) from window creation, and cleanup (`SDL_Quit()`) from window destruction.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation and the hints on the SubSystem init/quit.

Comment: i am happy to remove `SDL_Init()`/`SDL_Quit()` from my window creation/destruction code; it's only there because this was the only way i could make it work for now; hopefully the subsystems will make that easier.

Comment: as for SDL2, i would like to stick with the SDL-version that is comes with debian for now (which is unfortunately 1.2; there are (old) SDL1.3 packages available in the non-official "experimental" repositories, which afaiu is equivalent to SDL2)